# Issue with parsing in JAGS

Tags: r, jags

I am trying to estimate with multiple regression with 3 independent variables.

My JAGS model is running which is

```
modelstring = "
model {
for (i in 1:N){
y[i]  ̃ dnorm(y.hat[i], tau)
y.hat[i] <- beta0 + beta1 * x1[i] + beta2* x2[i] + beta3 * x3[i]
}
beta0  ̃ dnorm(0, .0001)
beta1  ̃ dnorm(0, .0001)
beta2  ̃ dnorm(0, .0001)
beta3  ̃ dnorm(0, .0001)
tau <- pow(sigma, -2)
sigma  ̃ dunif(0, 100)
}
"
writeLines(modelstring,con="model2.txt")
```

however, when I write out my function of

```
data3 = list("x1"= L_A$ell ,"x2"= d2$more.than.high, "x3" = L_A$meals, "y"= L_A$api00, "N" = length(L_A))
library("rjags")
out12 <- jags.model( "model2.txt", data = data3, n.chains = 3, 
                   n.adapt = 2000)
res12 <- coda.samples( out12, var = c("beta0", "beta1", "beta2" , "beta3" ,"sigma"),  10000)
summary(res12)
color_scheme_set("blue") 
mcmc_trace(res12, pars = c("beta0", "beta1", "beta2" , "beta3" "sigma"))
plot(res12)
```

it is not running, as it says there is an syntax error in parsing, stated by-

Error in jags.model("model2.txt", data = data3, n.chains = 3, n.adapt = 2000) :

Error parsing model file:
syntax error on line 4 near "�"

How can i fix this?

Comment: did you copy and paste your model from somewhere? The tilde (`~`) looks weird. Try replacing these values using the keyboard

Comment: I agree about the tilde. I can run the jags model no problem after deleting and retyping the `~`s.

Comment: Did it, and It worked. Thank you, can you explain the difference?

Comment: The difference is that you were using some weird character instead of `~`.